# Inversion of a symmetric and positive definite matrix with or without a column and row

Tags: matrices, inverse

Suppose to have a symmetric and positive definite matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ and suppose to know its inverse $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}$.

Let
$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{+}= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} & \mathbf{b} \\ \mathbf{b}^{T}& b_1 \\ \end{array}\right)$

and

$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{-} & \mathbf{c} \\ \mathbf{c}^{T}& c_1 \\ \end{array}\right)$

How can I find $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{-}^{-1}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{+}^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d:=b_1-b^T\Sigma^{-1}b\neq 0$.
The [block inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) gives
$$
\Sigma_+^{-1}=\pmatrix{\Sigma^{-1}+\frac{1}{d}\Sigma^{-1}bb^T\Sigma^{-1}&-\frac{1}{d}\Sigma^{-1}b\\-\frac{1}{d}b^T\Sigma^{-1}&\frac{1}{d}}.
$$
Note that $d\neq 0$ is the necessary and sufficient condition for the invertibility of $\Sigma_+$. Actually, if $\Sigma$ is SPD, $\Sigma_+$ is SPD as well iff $d>0$.

Similarly, we can write
$$
\Sigma^{-1}=\pmatrix{\Sigma_-^{-1}+\frac{1}{e}\Sigma_-^{-1}cc^T\Sigma_-^{-1}&-\frac{1}{e}\Sigma_-^{-1}c\\-\frac{1}{e}c^T\Sigma_-^{-1}&\frac{1}{e}}=:\pmatrix{X&x\\x^T&\xi}.
$$
Since $\Sigma$ is SPD, $e>0$.
We have
$$
\Sigma_-^{-1}=X-\frac{1}{e}\Sigma_-^{-1}cc^T\Sigma_-^{-1}=X-e\left(-\frac{1}{e}\Sigma_-^{-1}c\right)\left(-\frac{1}{e}\Sigma_-^{-1}c\right)^T=X-\frac{1}{\xi}xx^T.
$$

Comment: Just a minor comment. You don't define $e$

Comment: @niandra82 $e$ is defined similarly as $d$.

Comment: Yes I know, but maybe is better specify it in the answer for keep things clean